# Cat is not recognized (Makefile)

Tags: python, docker, makefile

I'm beginner, and I hope You can help me with my problem.
I use Makefile in my project, but when I try to run "cat" comand I get error with "cat is not recohnized...."

Its looks like this:

```
make start
cat environment/docker_cred.txt | docker login --username username --password-stdin
"cat" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
make: *** [docker_login] Error 255
```

But when i run it manually its work:

```
cat environment/docker_cred.txt | docker login --username username --password-stdin
Login Succeeded
```

Thanks

Comment: What's in the actual Makefile?  Are you, for example, manipulating the `PATH` variable somehow?

Comment: The default assumption by most people is that you will be using a POSIX system such as GNU/Linux (at least, if you're working with makefiles and docker).  if you're using a Windows system instead (as you appear to be) you should be sure to state that clearly up-front.

Comment: This error is coming from the Windows `cmd.exe` shell.  The Windows shell doesn't support things like the `cat` program, etc.  Presumably when you run the command manually you're doing it from some sort of POSIX shell like `bash`.  If you tried to run that command in a `cmd.exe` shell, you would see the same results you see when you run `make`.  Your version of `make` is built to run its recipes in the `cmd.exe` shell, and/or it can't find a POSIX shell to use.